Tailwind not applying on my Next.js app (firebase hosting)
I'm trying to host a Next app on firebase hosting. When I run the emulator to test it the tailwind css is not applying. It shows the following:
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

My tailwind config looks like this:
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;

When i run it locally with npm run devit works correctly, but in the emulator it doesn't. I don't know if it is because of this:
 Thank you for trying our early preview of Next.js support on Firebase Hosting.
   During the preview, support is best-effort and breaking changes can be expected. Proceed with caution.
   The integration is known to work with Next.js version 12 - 14.0. You may encounter errors.

I'm using next js 14.3.
Also another cause could be that I also have cloud functions in my repository, and something that has to do with paths, but i doubt it. This is the firebase.json in the root of the repository:
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "runtime": "python312",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": "/frontend",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}


The structure is the following:
-frontend
|
-functions

I don't know what else to do.
